# apache.commons.fileupload throws MalformedStreamException

Tags: java, file-upload, apache-commons

I have got this piece of code (I didn't write, just maintaining):

```
public class MyMultipartResolver extends CommonsMultipartResolver{    
  public List parseEmptyRequest(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, FileUploadException {
            String contentType = request.getHeader(CONTENT_TYPE);
            int boundaryIndex = contentType.indexOf("boundary=");

            InputStream input = request.getInputStream();

            byte[] boundary = contentType.substring(boundaryIndex + 9).getBytes();
            MultipartStream multi = new MultipartStream(input, boundary);
            multi.setHeaderEncoding(getHeaderEncoding());

            ArrayList items = new ArrayList();
            boolean nextPart = multi.skipPreamble();
            while (nextPart) {
                Map headers = parseHeaders(multi.readHeaders());
               // String fieldName = getFieldName(headers);

                String subContentType = getHeader(headers, CONTENT_TYPE);
                if (subContentType == null) {
                    FileItem item = createItem(headers, true);
                    OutputStream os = item.getOutputStream();
                    try {
                        multi.readBodyData(os);
                    } finally {
                        os.close();
                    }
                    items.add(item);
                } else {
                    multi.discardBodyData();
                }

                nextPart = multi.readBoundary();
            }

            return items;
        }
}
```

I am using commons-fileupload.jar version 1.2.1 and obviously the code is using some deprecated methods... 
Anyway, while trying to use this code to upload a very large file (780 MB) I get this:

```
org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$MalformedStreamException: Stream ended unexpectedly
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:983)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:887)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:89)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:94)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:64)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream.readBodyData(MultipartStream.java:593)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream.discardBodyData(MultipartStream.java:619)
```

that is thrown from 'multi.discardBodyData();' line.
**My question:** 
How can I avoid this error and be able to be able to succeed collecting the FileItems?

Comment: The browser connection is probably timing out. How long does it take before it happens?

Comment: It happens immediately, I run the server locally on my machine

Answer (score 0):

catch

```
(org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream.MalformedStreamException e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();

            return ERROR;
        }
```

Catch the exception and handle it via ..either `InputStream` or `Return Error` use it in struts action tag

Comment: It does not answer OP's question.